# Trying to intercept a specific touch on object added to scene - how does ccTouchBegan work?

Tags: touch, cocos2d-x, ccsprite

EDIT: Ok I found the solution by simply watching the TouchesTest cocos2d-x sample. The only thing thas was missing, was to test if the touch location was contained in the sprite rect and claim the touch. Thus, i was able to replace my previous code with that one

```
bool Artifact::claimTouch(CCTouch* pTouch)
{
    CCPoint touchLocation = pTouch->getLocation();
    CCRect boundingBox = this->boundingBox();

    return boundingBox.containsPoint(touchLocation);
}

bool Artifact::ccTouchBegan(CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent)
{
    if (claimTouch(pTouch))
    {
        CCLog("id:%i", this->id);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

END OF EDIT

I am trying to intercept a specific touch on a object I added on the scene.

The code for adding two objects:

```
Artifact* artifact1 = new Artifact(1);
Artifact* artifact2 = new Artifact(2);
CCRect cropRect = CCRectZero;
cropRect.size = CCSize(50,50);
artifact1->initWithFile("rock_small.png", cropRect);
artifact1->setPosition(CCPoint(100, 100));
artifact2->initWithFile("grey_rock.jpg", cropRect);
artifact2->setPosition(CCPoint(300, 200));
```

And here is what I obtain on my simulator

[image: screenshot]

The code for my Artifact class

//.H

```
class Artifact : public CCSprite, public CCTargetedTouchDelegate
{
public:
    Artifact(int id) : id(id), pressed(false){};

    virtual void onEnter();
    virtual void onExit();

    bool ccTouchBegan(CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent);
private:
    int id;
    bool pressed;
};
```

//.CPP

```
void Artifact::onEnter()
{
    CCSprite::onEnter();
    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->addTargetedDelegate(this, 0, true);
}

void Artifact::onExit()
{
    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->removeDelegate(this);
    CCSprite::onExit();
}

bool Artifact::ccTouchBegan(CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent)
{
    CCLog("id:%i", this->id);

    return true;
}
```

And whatever point I click on the screen (even if i dont click one of the two squares), ccTouchBegan is called on the second artifact (output is "id:2"). It's like the CCSprite I added in last position (i.e top z-coordinate) covers the entire screen and prevents me from accessing elements under it.

Any idea what can be the cause?

Comment: Hey i have the same problem , did you found solution ?
see my question :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188095/created-many-ccsprits-but-when-triggering-cctouchbegan-gives-the-last-one-allway

Answer (score 1):

watching the TouchesTest cocos2d-x sample

a few key points

```
class Paddle : public CCSprite, public CCTargetedTouchDelegate
    virtual void onEnter();
    virtual void onExit();
    bool containsTouchLocation(CCTouch* touch);
    virtual bool ccTouchBegan(CCTouch* touch, CCEvent* event);
    virtual void ccTouchMoved(CCTouch* touch, CCEvent* event);
    virtual void ccTouchEnded(CCTouch* touch, CCEvent* event);
```

this should solve  the question